# Issue installing openai in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, openai-api

Hi after the chrismas break I have problems installing openai in Google Colab

I'm doing this. Which worked util mid december 2023:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install --upgrade --quiet openai

import openai
```

Now I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-727253859e14> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install --upgrade --quiet openai')
      3 
----> 4 import openai

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/_utils/_streams.py in <module>
      1 from typing import Any
----> 2 from typing_extensions import Iterator, AsyncIterator
      3 
      4 
      5 def consume_sync_iterator(iterator: Iterator[Any]) -> None:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterator' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

I tested installing older versons of openai and also upgrading and uninstall+install of typing_extensions. But until now without success.

Comment: I tried using your code and It works fine for me, didn't get any error. Could the problem be something else you maybe did to colab?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this now. Which solves it in Colab:

```
!pip install cohere 
!pip install tiktoken
!pip uninstall typing-extensions -y quiet
!pip install typing-extensions==4.5.0 --quiet 
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability
!pip install --upgrade --quiet openai

import openai
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the notebook kernel. Sometimes when a package like langchain is install with pip first there can be an issue. You can change the order of the pip installs or just restart the kernel after pip install. :)

```
!pip install openai
```

Then restart the kernel session.

> Ctrl + M

After that you can

```
import openai
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Matthew works. But it seems tedious to restart each time you want to run the collab. Is there a way to do this with code?

I've found a thread on the openai forum where a user suggested this:

> I changed the import of the file that is trying to import Iterator
> from typing_extensions in this way (On Googlo Colab):
>
> ```
> %%writefile /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/_utils/_streams.py
> from typing import Any
> from typing_extensions import AsyncIterator
> from typing import Iterator # import Iterator from the correct library
>
> def consume_sync_iterator(iterator: Iterator[Any]) -> None:
>     for _ in iterator:
>         ...
>
> async def consume_async_iterator(iterator: AsyncIterator[Any]) -> None:
>     async for _ in iterator:
>         ...
> ```
>
> And that works for me.

This worked for me as well, but editing the file each time seemed not as elegant as well.